# Shopping basket without using any predefined collection libraries

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following assignment:

> Implement a basic shopping basket without using any predefined
>   collection libraries.  Please comment your code to support your design
>   decision and any assumption that you make.  Your shopping basket must
>   support the following two methods:-
>
> 1. `void add(Item i, int n)  - adds n copies of i to the basket`
> 2. `int totalPrice()`  - compute the total price of the basket. The
>      total price must be returned in constant time; however, `void add(Item
>      i, int n)`  does not need to be returned in constant time.

I have implemented the shopping class like this but don't getting the clue how to implement totalPrice method.

```
public class Shopping {

public void add(Item i, int n){
    int totalCost = (int) (i.getItemPrice()*n);
}


public static void main(String arg[]){
    Item item = new Item();
    item.setItemPrice(10);
    Shopping shopping = new Shopping();
    shopping.add(item,4);
}

}
```

I have been asked this in a test. Does anyone can give me some idea how this can be done?

Comment: Do you know how to create a class in Java? Are you taking the test right now?

Comment: Hi Birryree, please check my updated question.

Comment: You need a place to store your Items. We've been told that you can't use the Collections framework. Do you know of another way to store Objects/values?

Comment: should I use a InputStream to store values?

Comment: No, I don't think an InputStream is applicable here. There is a basic construct in Java that lets you store a number of Objects or values in it. You would have learned about them early on. The other option (and it depends how much you have been taught, and whether you're at the level yet) is to write your own data structure to store these objects. Is the assignment to write your own LinkedList or similar?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for giving me clue. Its not mentioned in assignment that I should use LinkedList or not. Yes I can try it using linkedList. Also, I didn't get the second part "The total price must be returned in constant time". What does this mean here?

Comment: void add(Item i, int n) should add an item to the cart. But as per your code, it is calculating total price. You can try a LinkedList<Item> to represent the collection. And ideally I think the Item class should have a getter/setter like getNumOfCopies() and setNumofCopies(int n). Just some hints.

Comment: "The total price must be returned in constant time" this means that whether there are 10 items in the shopping basket or 10million items, it should not take any longer to run the totalPrice() method. What this essentially means is that when totalPrice() is called you are not allowed to loop through all your items (regardless of how they are stored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a member variable in the class, that you can used to store the total price in the basket. And every time you add items to the basket you can update the value of this variable.
Let's say we add a member variable:

```
private int total;
```

Then modify your add(...) method to add the value of totalCost to total and the only thing you should do in your totalPrice() method is return the value of total. You can initialize the variable total in the constructor.